# coverage badge is stuck on "unknown"

Tags: travis-ci, coverage.py, coveralls

I am trying to use coveralls.io to show a coverage badge for my tests, but the coverage badge is stuck on "unknown".
The relevant repo is here: https://github.com/Noah-Lc/simple-blog-rest-api
When I look at coveralls.io for that repo I see the same "coverage: unknown" status:
However, the individual builds are being correctly sent to coveralls.io: https://coveralls.io/jobs/46387537

Comment: The badge is for the `master` branch, but the coveralls build shows that the branch is unknown.

Comment: @Alasdair yes i don't know why

Comment: Related Github issue (no solution as of 2019-12-05): https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/1201

Comment: I have resolved this problem.  In my case, I forgot to install coveralls inside Travis CI, and it was failing silently.  After adding an installation of coveralls to `.travis.yml`, it worked correctly.  Could the same problem happen for you?

Comment: can you show me how you install it inside travis.yml

Comment: @Noah Lc in the `.travis.yml` section  `before_install:   - pip install --user cpp-coveralls`
then, in the section  `after_success: - coveralls --exclude lib --exclude tests --gcov-options '\-lp' `
Note: I have observed coverage badge "unknown" even after successful build and passage to coveralls. The next morning, I have just reloaded the web-page of coveralls.io and the badge appeared with coverage numbers!